# Redactor wysiwyg : how to set initial content for the textarea from server side itself?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, redactor

When the user logs in, and is taken to the main page - that user might have multiple redactor editors on his page.

Since I'm generating the page on the server I want to populate each of editors with data the user had saved earlier.

Hence, the question is :

> How do I populate these editors from server side itself ?

I tried to set the **value** attribute of the textarea, but that didn't work.

My php code is simple :

```
<?php
   echo '<textarea id="editor_" ' + $user_id + ' class='editor' value="'+$savedContent+'"></textarea>';
?>
```

My javascript code is pretty simple :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".editor").redactor();
});
```

Hence when the page is loaded, all the textareas with "**editor**" as a class turn into redactor editors.

As you see above, each of the editors has a unique "**user_id**" attached to them.

In my php how should I generate the textarea, so when the javascript runs, all of them are populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not especially aware of `Redactor`, but maybe just place the content inside the `<textarea>`, as the `<textarea>` works differently than a text `<input>` :

```
<?php echo "<textarea id='editor_$user_id' class='editor'>$savedContent</textarea>"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that too. But redactor takes it out when it does it's thing.

Comment: Actually, I think I should try that again, there was an error in the html the server had pasted. But I'm worried about putting it like that, 'coz it doesn't seem secure.. A user could embed scripts while saving.. In either case, let me try this first. If it does work, then security would be the next hurdle :)